# Unmarshalling Error: Namespace URIs and local names to the unmarshaller needs to be interned

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I've created a web reference to a SOAP web service in C#.
If i browse to the service or use POSTMAN for example to test i get back a response as expected.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:openResponse xmlns:ns1="http://auto.api.com/">
            <return xmlns:ns2="http://auto.api.com/">
                <error>User/pass incorrect</error>
            </return>
        </ns1:openResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The code I am running below is quite simple, but when its connecting to the service i'm getting this error:

> Unmarshalling Error: Namespace URIs and local names to the
>   unmarshaller needs to be interned

```
var connect = new SOAP();

        var open = connect.open(new Open
        {
            user = "user",
            pass = "pass"
        });
```

Any suggestions? I cant find anything that suggests how to sort it out. I've never seen this error connecting to a web service before.

Full Exception:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Unmarshalling
>   Error: Namespace URIs and local names to the unmarshaller needs to be
>   interned.     at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   TestingConsole.web.SOAP.open(xOpen open1) in
>   c:\Users\pm\Source\Repos\TestingConsole\Web
>   References\web\Reference.cs:line 755    at
>   TestingConsole.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\pm\Source\Repos\TestingConsole\Form1.cs:line 32

And part of reference.cs it is referring to

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace="http://auto.api.com/", ResponseNamespace="http://auto.api.com/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public xOpenResponse open([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("open", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] xOpen open1) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("open", new object[] {
                open1});
    return ((xOpenResponse)(results[0]));
}
```

Full exception as a service reference:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Unmarshalling Error: Namespace
>   URIs and local names to the unmarshaller needs to be interned.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at TestingConsole.SOAP.open(open request)
>   at TestingConsole.SOAP.TestingConsole.SOAP.open(open request) in
>   c:\Users\pm\Source\Repos\TestingConsole\Service
>   References\service\Reference.cs:line 7621    at
>   TestingConsole.SOAP.open(xOpen open1) in
>   c:\Users\pm\Source\Repos\TestingConsole\Service
>   References\service\Reference.cs:line 7627    at
>   TestingConsole.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\pm\Source\Repos\TestingConsole\Form1.cs:line 29

And the bits from the reference.cs file its referring to:

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    TestingConsole.service.openResponse TestingConsole.service.SOAP.open(TestingConsole.service.open request) {
        return base.Channel.open(request);
    }


public TestingConsole.service.xOpenResponse open(TestingConsole.service.xOpen open1) {
    TestingConsole.service.open inValue = new TestingConsole.service.open();
    inValue.open1 = open1;
    TestingConsole.service.openResponse retVal = ((TestingConsole.service.SOAP)(this)).open(inValue);
    return retVal.@return;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen that error, but why not use "Add Service Reference"? "Add Web Reference" is the old-style, legacy technology that should not be used in new development.

Comment: Hi,when its a web reference the exception comes from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException. Changing to a service reference I get the same error but from System.ServiceModel.FaultException

Comment: You are not getting an error. You are getting an exception. For troubleshooting purposes, please put a `try {/* your code here */} catch (Exception ex){Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());Console.ReadLine();throw;}` then post the full exception _in your question_.

Comment: Hi, have updated question to include the full exception. It seems to be an issue with the reference.cs file?

Comment: Please try it again with a service reference and again post the exception. I'm concerned that it's a `SoapHeaderException` but your example XML does not contain a SOAP Header.

Comment: hi, i have amended the question with it as a service reference, thanks

Comment: The fact that you get the same message form both networking stacks, and quite different stack traces, suggests that the message is being sent to you by the _server_. You could confirm this by watching the network using Fiddler or the like. I'm sure you'll see that the server is sending you a `<soap:Fault>` element containing this error.

Comment: hi, thanks for all your help. I have discovered its because the service expects the namespace to be in the soap envelope, and not in the body where .net has added in the auto generated reference.cs. any suggestions of how to intercept the message to add the namespace to the soap envelope? thanks

Comment: Your service is broken. It doesn't matter where the namespace declaration is located, as long is it is located before it is used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to fix this was to remove the RequestNamespace from the methods it generated in the Reference.cs. This then meant it sent the correctly formatted request to the service

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was solved by blanking the WrapperNamespace attribute parameter, so for example:

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="confirmReservation", WrapperNamespace="http://autogenerated.OTWebServiceApi.sampleservice.com/", IsWrapped=true)]
```

becomes

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="confirmReservation", WrapperNamespace="", IsWrapped=true)]
```